# How big should I make my image specified in og:image?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm adding og meta tags for a page, including `og:image`. Ideally, how large should the specified image be?

Answer (score 0):

we have to use at least 200px for both dimension,else when you using the facebook debugging tools, it will show you the error message something like "your og:image must atleast 200px or xxxx"

i try to use a small version last time at my facebook app ->www.wootube.woolei.com, but end up when i share my page on facebook, the image are not render properly.